# How to report memory leaks in Android/Java using PhantomReference

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, phantom-reference

After reconstructing an old piece of code I once wrote, then forgot, now rewritten... I am putting it here as a wiki for all to use :-)

So, basically: If you got memory leaks in a complex Android app, containing images and cross-references. How would you go and find which (type of) objects are leaking? There are a few (very hard to learn and use) tools provided with the Android SDK. Probably there are more which I don't know. Yet, Java do provide PhantomReference as a mean to do this, even though going through the mess required to set up the required classes can be much work (And nasty too... [JDK-8034946](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8034946)).

But what is the most simple/effective way of doing so? My solution below.

Answer (score 1):

[LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) is a 3rd party library which automatically detects memory leaks, after adding the dependency you can add the following line to your application class:

```
LeakCanary.install(this);
```

The library provides a nice notification & trace of the leak, you can also define your own reference watchers (although the default ones seem to work fairly well).

Comment: Nice, but do you need to load and manage the heap dump myself, or is it handled internally by the library?

Answer (score 0):

My solution in one class: "MemCheck"

To monitor any object, just call:

```
MemCheck.add( this ); // in any class constructor
```

This will "monitor" the number of objects allocated, and most importantly - Deallocated.

To log the leaks at any required time, call:

```
MemCheck.countAndLog();
```

As an alternative, set MemCheck.periodic = 5 (number of seconds).
This will report the number of monitored objects in memory every 5 seconds. It will also conveniently log the used/free memory.

So, MemCheck.java:

```
package com.xyz.util;

import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class MemCheck
{
    private static final boolean                enabled = true;
    private static final int                    periodic = 0; // seconds, 0 == disabled
    private static final String                 tag = MemCheck.class.getName();
    private static TreeMap<String, RefCount>    mObjectMap = new TreeMap<String, RefCount>(); 
    private static Runnable                     mPeriodicRunnable = null;
    private static Handler                      mPeriodicHandler = null;

    public static void add( Object object )
    {
        if( !enabled )
            return;

        synchronized( mObjectMap )
        {
            String name = object.getClass().getName();
            RefCount queue = mObjectMap.get( name );
            if( queue == null )
            {
                queue = new RefCount();
                mObjectMap.put( name, queue );
                queue.add( object );
            }
            else
                queue.add( object );
        }
    }

    public static void countAndLog()
    {
        if( !enabled )
            return;
        System.gc();
        Log.d( tag, "Log report starts" );
        Iterator<Entry<String, RefCount>> entryIter = mObjectMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while( entryIter.hasNext() )
        {
            Entry<String, RefCount> entry = entryIter.next(); 
            String name = entry.getKey();
            RefCount refCount = entry.getValue();
            Log.d( tag, "Class " + name + " has " + refCount.countRefs() + " objects in memory." );
        }

        logMemoryUsage();
        Log.d( tag, "Log report done" );
    }

    public static void logMemoryUsage()
    {
        if( !enabled )
            return;
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Log.d( tag, "Max Heap: " + runtime.maxMemory() / 1048576 + " MB, Used: " + runtime.totalMemory() / 1048576 +
               " MB, Free: " + runtime.freeMemory() / 1024 + " MB" );

        if( periodic > 0 )
        {
            if( mPeriodicRunnable != null )
                mPeriodicHandler.removeCallbacks( mPeriodicRunnable );
            if( mPeriodicHandler == null )
                mPeriodicHandler = new Handler();
            mPeriodicRunnable = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    mPeriodicRunnable = null;
                    countAndLog();
                    logMemoryUsage(); // this will run the next
                }
            };

            mPeriodicHandler.postDelayed( mPeriodicRunnable, periodic * 1000 );
        }
    }

    private static class RefCount
    {
        private ReferenceQueue<Object>  mQueue = new ReferenceQueue<Object>();
        private HashSet<Object>         mRefHash = new HashSet<Object>(); 
        private int                     mRefCount = 0;

        public void add( Object o )
        {
            synchronized( this )
            {
                mRefHash.add( new PhantomReference<Object>( o, mQueue ) ); // Note: References MUST be kept alive for their references to be enqueued
                mRefCount++;
            }
        }

        public int countRefs()
        {
            synchronized( this )
            {
                Object ref;
                while( ( ref = mQueue.poll() ) != null )
                {
                    mRefHash.remove( ref );
                    mRefCount--;
                }

                return mRefCount;
            }
        }

    }
}
```